# Spinner to send a different value

Tags: android, android-spinner

How to make the spinner send a different value other the value specified:

For eg. My strings.xml has the following thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Search the Movie Title</string>
    <string name="button_send">Search</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

    <string-array name="title_type">
        <item>All Types</item>
        <item>Feature Film</item>
        <item>TV Series</item>
        <item>Video Game</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

now, when the user clicks on All Types, instead of All Types, i need alltypes to been sent. The reason being i need to construct a URL which accepts "alltypes" to fetch data.

I have my MainActivity.java code as:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btn;
private EditText edit;
private Spinner spinner;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    //Log.v("EditText", edit.getText().toString());
                    //Log.v("Spinner", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    //if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()=="All Types")

                    String url="http://cs-server.xxx.edu:23405/examples/servlet/HelloWorldExample?title="+edit.getText().toString()+"&type="+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Log.v("url",url);
                }
            });



ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.title_type,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

 //String url="http://cs-server.xxx.edu:23405/examples/servlet/HelloWorldExample?tit  le="+edit.getText().toString()+"&type="+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
  // Log.v("url",url);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        //Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});


}

private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String response = "";
      for (String url : urls) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
          InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

          BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
          String s = "";
          while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            response += s;
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      textView.setText(result);
    }
  }

  public void readWebpage(View view) {
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://facebook.com"});

  }
}
```

I am fairly new to Android Programming.
Any suggestions as to how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 yourspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) 
            {
                String selecteditem = yourspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                selecteditem = selecteditem.equals("All Types")?selecteditem..replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase():selecteditem;
               // removes the space and converts to lowercase
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

2nd Option.

```
 String[] customarr = {"feature,tv_series,game","feature","tv_series","game"};
 String selecteditem = customarr[yourspinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]
```

Comment: I get ur point, but what i am trying to say is that only in the case of "All Types", i need alltypes. there are other 3 spinner options, i need individual data for each of them...say for example, for"Feature Film", i need feature and so on ... Also, after forming the URL, i need to fetch the json data from my server and parse it. Any ideas how can i do it, or any tutorial u can refer me to.?

Comment: ok then do then check with position in if condition as if(position == 0) then change it to lowercase

Comment: can you, modify the code for one of the values just to show me an example...say for "All Types" i need all_types to be generated....you can see that i had tried using if statement, but i am not familiar with what functions to use...

Comment: @PSN, just check the edited answer. I use condition operator instead of If condition. check it

Comment: check this selecteditem = selecteditem.equals("All Types")?selecteditem..replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase():selecteditem;

Comment: ok..cant i use the replace method to manually replace all the values and  use the replaced value to create my url..? What method should i use? i mean what function..?

Comment: but then again its not necessary that I need to make all of the spinner options to small case. Heres what I need:
"All Types" converted to "feature,tv_series,game"
"Feature film"--->"feature
"TV Series"-->"tv_series"
"Video Game"--> "game".

Comment: then its better to maintain separate array in your activity and get position from the spinner and use the array value with the spinner position

Comment: ok....thats what i want an example....because i am new to java programming....can you just modify ur code to let me see what exactly what you mean..:-)

Comment: cant i use replaceAll method to replace the entire string itself one by one 4 times..?

Comment: ok..I will try that....any ideas as to how to parse JSON data..i need a good tutorial for it...

Comment: try googling first. As google is our best friend . try to share your problem with google first

Answer (score 1):

You can use following approach.

```
<string-array name="title_values">
        <item>alltypes</item>
        <item>featurefilm</item>
        <item>tvseries</item>
        <item>videogame</item>
</string-array>
```

Modification in the code will be

```
String[] titleValues = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.title_values);



 titleSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > adapterView, View view,
     int position, long id) {

         String selectedItem = titleValues[position];

     }

     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <? > arg0) {


     }
 });
```

Comment: But the spinner needs to display "All types" to the user.
I am putting my code in the question. could you guide me what exacty to do..

Comment: What am i also trying to do is that whenever the user clicks on"All Types", alltypes needs to be sent to form the url of the server i am trying to call.My server will return me a Json data, which i need to parse . Can you guide me in doing the same or any other tutorial which i can refer to.?